# mvn not found when executed via Jenkins shell script

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, maven-3

I have set M2_HOME under Manage Jenkins -> configure system -> Environment variables and also under Manage Jenkins -> global tool configuration.

When I use maven project, it is working fine.
But when I use freestyle project and execute shell, it throws an error "mvn not found".

But when I give `echo $M2_HOME` in Execute shell, it shows the correct path.
Also, when I tried `$M2_HOME/mvn compile`, it worked fine.
I could not figure out the exact issue.

**Error**
[Compile]

```
$ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1984982949384007169.sh

+ mvn --version

/tmp/jenkins1984982949384007169.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins1984982949384007169.sh: mvn: not found

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: `M2_HOME` is not interpreted by a shell interpreter - `PATH` is.

Comment: Try Setting it in a bash profile and try loading it with source ~/.bash_profile command.

Comment: I have tried that too.. [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262542/stefan-hanke) and [anushal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4243319/anshul-gupta)

Answer (score 0):

The shell which executes the `mvn` command doesn't know that the path for the script in in the `M2_HOME` variable. The shell will only look at commands listed in the `$PATH` variable.

So there are two solutions:

- Always use `"$M2_HOME/mvn"` to execute Maven (or rather `"$M2_HOME/bin/mvn"` since `M2_HOME` should point to the folder which contains `bin` and `lib` and not to the script itself).
- Change the path at the top of the script to make the shell search in the right place:

  ```
  export PATH="$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH"
  ```

  That probably only makes sense when you run Maven more than once in the script.